# include from output buffer?

Tags: php, include

I have a dynamically generated page with some BBcode on. 
For example I have one named `[PHP]file.php[/PHP]`..

The output is buffered using `ob_start("parser);`. Is it possible to replace `[PHP]file.php[/PHP]` with `include("file.php");` on the output buffer?

```
<?php
function parser($buffer){
   //This is where I want 'it to happen'
}

ob_start("parser");
?>
<html>
..........
<body>
Some text<br /><br />
[PHP]file1.php[/PHP]<br /><br />
More text..<br /><br />
[PHP]file2.php[/PHP]

<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I hope your users don't provide this BBCode.

Comment: Why do not `<?php ... ?>` codes work for you? You won't need to code anything for that, it's a built-in feature of the language.

Answer (score -1):

Sure; replacing it with a call to `include()` will execute `file.php` and add the output to the buffer. Make sure to do some checks on the filename before including it, to prevent remote script injection etc!!

Comment: Hmm.. Think I'm gonna be more precise. Let's say I have this page:

Edit: http://pastebin.com/iEC8naFM    

How do I replace BOTH those [PHP] with include? Can I just text replace it to <?php include($file);?>, or?????

Comment: That just outputs plain text. This is my parser function: http://pastebin.com/7fsmwPD4

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all.

Comment: The question wasn't clear. And where is your answer if you know so well?